# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMPDF::loadHtml() i

Tags: dompdf

I'm trying out DOMPDF and include this file as instructed: dompdf_config.inc.php.  But when I go to the page, I get a fatal error, as in the title.  It appears the file with classes isn't be loaded or something is going on.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using 0.6.x (based on the presence of the dompdf_config.inc.php file) the correct method is `$dompdf->load_html();` [[wiki](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Usage/3c811d0f41879e15c7b394f13cd84bb9de9aaf72#method-summary)].

Comment: Thanks   Turned out I saw that when I looked in the files.